# Vue how to trigger click on links based on interval

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my `vue`-app I have a list of links, which I want to be triggered automatically one by one by a default interval, lets say after 3 seconds, the first link gets triggered, then after another 3 seconds, link 2 gets triggered... so its kind of a carousel/autoplay with links I want to achieve, but I don't really know how to solve that.

here is my code:

```
<li v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index" :class="slideIndex === index ? 'active' : ''" @click="slideIndex = index" ref="slide">
 {{ slide.title }}
</li>
```

and then I thought somethinbg like this:

```
mounted() {    
  Object.keys(this.$refs.slide).forEach((el) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.$refs.slide[el].click();
    }, 3000);
  });
},
```

but this triggers all links and does not seem to be right at all, but its just a slight idea...

Can someone help me out?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What you want is to increment the index every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend doing this by simulating a click on the link.

How about setting the element you want to be active in your code?

I assume `slideIndex` is the current selected slide?

You could try something like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.slideIndex = this.slideIndex < this.slides.length - 1 ? (this.slideIndex += 1) : 0;
}, 3000);
```

So you add +1 every time the interval is triggered and cycle through the slides. If it's at the end `slideIndex` gets reset and starts at 00